# C# Break Line of Text considering Uppercase and Lowercase

Tags: c#, text, size, line, string-length

I'm making in Unity a Dialog Box with Public Variables. I put the Texts and the Dialog Box Typed in sequence.
I wanna just put the Text and make the code break lines automically, and the problem is that I can't just set a Limit of Characters, cause exist a big difference if I try to use a lot of Uppercase Letters or just a little
I need a help to Break Line for Occupied Space, and not a Limit of Characters

Sorry if I wrote a confused question, I'm trying to learn more english ^^